# How to amend a string with a variable?

Tags: powershell, variables, copy, structure

I am trying to copy PDFs from one server to another preserving the  folder structure, I have come up with the following script.

I am trying to find the data contained in the variable `$Server` in another variable `$newdes` and remove it. However, this fails to happen. If you inspect the variable `$newdes` you will see that it contains the data stored in `$Server`, which I need to remove in order for the copy to commence.

As it stands the variable of `$newdes` contains

```
C:\Temp\ \file\homedrives\home
```

It might not show but I see double `\` as a UNC file path.

I need it to read `C:\temp\homedrives\home`.

I am guessing because of the `\ \file` this fails to start the copy, if this is the case, somebody advise how to get this working.

**Amended as requested:**

```
$Criteria = *.pdf
$Trial = c:\temp\folders.txt
$Server = \\file
$Path = homedrives\home
$des = $Path
$safe = Get-Content $Trial
$safe | ForEach-Object {
    # find drive-delimeter
    $first = $_.IndexOf("\\");

    if ($first -eq 1) {
        # stripe it
        $newdes = Join-Path -Path $des -ChildPath @($_.Substring(0, 1) + $_.Substring(2))[0]
    } else {
        $newdes = Join-Path -Path $des -ChildPath $_
    }
    $err = 0
  > $folder = Split-Path -Path $newdes -Parent

    $err = 0
    # check if folder exists"
    $void = Get-Item $folder -ErrorVariable err -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($err.Count -ne 0) {
        # create when it doesn't
        $void = New-Item -Path $folder -ItemType Directory -Force -Verbose
    }

    $void = Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination $des -Force -Verbose
    #$void = Copy-Item -Path $_ -Include $Criteria -Destination $Path $Choice -Recurse -Container
    #$void = Copy-Item -Path $Files -Include $Criteria -Destination $newdes -Force -Verbose -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Write-Host $_
}
Write-Host $newdes
```

Comment: Are you able to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to save people having to wade through tons of non-essential code?

Comment: I appreciate that you have provided the code that you are working with. In this case however, a lot of people will not take the time to read all this code looking for the place where you are having an issue. That is compounded by the fact that your issue isn't really all that well explained. Please take the time to creat a [MCVE] that demonstrates the exact problem. Often the mere act of creating an MCVE will clarify the issue in your own mind and you will find the solution yourself.

Comment: Why don't you just null out `$newdes` before you copy and replace the value with what you need? `$newdes = $null; $newdes = '\\SomePath\You\Want\'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't use the -Recurse switch?

```
$source     = 'C:\source'
$dest       = 'C:\dest'
$extensions = @('*.pdf')

Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $dest -Include $extensions -Force -Recurse
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 0):

ok, thanks for the assistance, I have now solved the issue, but it has presented another. Will post another question.

The solution to the above is to use

> -filter "*.pdf"

Below is a copy of my code

```
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")
Function Select-Server
    {
         param([string]$Description="Select Folder",[string]$RootFolder="Desktop")

     [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null     

     $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
     $objForm.Rootfolder = $Server
     $objForm.Description = $Description
     $objForm.ShowNewFolderButton = $false
     $Show = $objForm.ShowDialog()
     If ($Show -eq "OK")
     {
         Return $objForm.SelectedPath + "\"
     }
     Else
     {
        Write-Error "Operation cancelled by user."
     }
    }
    Function Select-FolderDialog
    {
         param([string]$Description="Select Folder",[string]$RootFolder="Desktop")

     [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null     

     $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
     $objForm.Rootfolder = $RootFolder
     $objForm.Description = $Description
     $objForm.ShowNewFolderButton = $false
     $Show = $objForm.ShowDialog()
     If ($Show -eq "OK")
     {
         Return $objForm.SelectedPath
     }
     Else
     {
        Write-Error "Operation cancelled by user."
     }
    }
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null
$Server = "\\" + [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Please choose a Server to search", "Server Choice")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null
$Choice = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Please choose a File Path to search", "File Path Choice")  + "\"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null
$Ext = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Please choose a File type i.e. *.PST", "Location Choice") 
#$Ext.ToUpper()
$Criteria = "*." + $Ext
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null
#$FPath = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Please choose a path to copy to", "Location Choice") 
$Path = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Please choose a folder to store the data", "Path Choice") + "\"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null
#$Name = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Please choose a filename", "File Name Choice")
$Search = $Server +"\"+ $Choice 
$FileName = $Path
$Info = $Path + "FileCopy.txt"
$Trial = $Path + "Folders.txt"
$Trial2 = $Path + "Ammended Folders.txt"
$Type = $Path + "$Ext's.txt".ToUpper()
#$Server2 = "\" + $Server
#$File = $Path + $Name
if( -Not (Test-Path -Path $Path ) )
{
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $Path |out-null
}
Else{
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('The directory already exists','Error','Ok','Error')
}
$properties = @(
    'Directory'
    ' '
    'Name'
    ' '
    @{
        Label = 'Size'
        Expression = {
            if ($_.Length -ge 1GB)
            {
                '{0:F2} GB' -f ($_.Length / 1GB)
            }
            elseif ($_.Length -ge 1MB)
            {
                '{0:F2} MB' -f ($_.Length / 1MB)
            }
            elseif ($_.Length -ge 1KB)
            {
                '{0:F2} KB' -f ($_.Length / 1KB)
            }
            else
            {
                '{0} bytes' -f $_.Length
            }
        }
        }
        $result = Get-ChildItem -Path $Search -Recurse -Include $Criteria -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  ) | Out-Null
  $Result
#Get-ChildItem -Path $Search -Recurse -Include *.pst -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
$Folders = (get-childitem -Path $Search | where-object { $_.PSIsContainer }).Count

If (Test-Path $Search) {
    <#Write-Host
    Write-Host "Listing All  Found In $Path" -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
    Write-Host "=========================================" -ForegroundColor "Yellow"#>

    Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms

    ## -- Create The Progress-Bar
    $ObjForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $ObjForm.Text = "Progress-Bar of searched folders"
    $ObjForm.Height = 100
    $ObjForm.Width = 500
    $ObjForm.BackColor = "White"

    $ObjForm.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle
    $ObjForm.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen

    ## -- Create The Label
    $ObjLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $ObjLabel.Text = "Starting. Please wait ... "
    $ObjLabel.Left = 5
    $ObjLabel.Top = 10
    $ObjLabel.Width = 500 - 20
    $ObjLabel.Height = 15
    $ObjLabel.Font = "Tahoma"
    ## -- Add the label to the Form
    $ObjForm.Controls.Add($ObjLabel)

    $PB = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
    $PB.Name = "PowerShellProgressBar"
    $PB.Value = 0
    $PB.Style="Continuous"

    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 500 - 40
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 20
    $PB.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $PB.Left = 5
    $PB.Top = 40
    $ObjForm.Controls.Add($PB)

    ## -- Show the Progress-Bar and Start The PowerShell Script
    $ObjForm.Show() | Out-Null
    $ObjForm.Focus() | Out-NUll
    $ObjLabel.Text = "Starting. Please wait ... "
    $ObjForm.Refresh()

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
 Out-Null
    ## -- Execute The PowerShell Code and Update the Status of the Progress-Bar

    $result = Get-ChildItem -Path $Search -Recurse -Include $Criteria -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
    $Counter = 0
    ForEach ($Item In $Result) {
        ## -- Calculate The Percentage Completed
        $Counter++
        [Int]$Percentage = ($Counter/$Result.Count)*100
        $PB.Value = $Percentage
        $ObjLabel.Text = "Scanning $Folders Folders For $Criteria in $Search"
        #$ObjLabel.Text = "Found $counter $Criteria in $Search"
        $ObjForm.Refresh()
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 150
        # -- $Item.Name
        #"`t" + $Item.Path

    }

    $ObjForm.Close()
    #Write-Host "`n"
}
Else {
    #Write-Host
    #Write-Host "`t Cannot Execute The Script." -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
    #Write-Host "`t $Search Does Not Exist in the System." -ForegroundColor "Yellow"
    #Write-Host
}
Out-Null
Sort-Object -Property DirectoryName |

Format-Table -Property $properties |

out-file $Info



$Search | out-file -Append $Trial 
#$Search | Out-File -Append $Trial2


$result | out-file -Append $Info

$result | Select Name | out-file -Append $Type


$des = $Path
#$PDFs= get-content $Type
$safe = Get-Content $Trial
#$Ten = @($Criteria)
$safe | ForEach-Object{
    #find drive-delimeter
    $first=$_.IndexOf("\\");
    if($first -eq 1){
        #stripe it
    $newdes=Join-Path -Path $des -ChildPath @($_.Substring(0,1)+$_.Substring(2))[0]    
        }
    else{
        $newdes=Join-Path -Path $des -ChildPath $_
            }
    $err=0
    $folder=Split-Path -Path $newdes -Parent
    $err=0
    #check if folder exists"
    $void=Get-Item $folder -ErrorVariable err  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if($err.Count -ne 0){
        #create when it doesn't
        $void=New-Item -Path $folder -ItemType Directory -Force -Verbose
        }  
$void=Copy-Item -Path $_ -destination $newdes -Filter $Criteria -recurse -Container -Force -Verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    write-host $_
    }
    write-host $newdes
```

> **$void=Copy-Item -Path $_ -destination $newdes -Filter $Criteria -recurse -Container -Force -Verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue**